# Safe and simple strtol()

Tags: c, formatting, api

Until today, in the few cases where I needed something like this, it had been in simple programs which only I used, and where I didn't care about security, so I used the simple `atoi()`.

However, today I needed to do that for a some more serious program, and I researched about the many different forms that are out there to go from a string to a number:  [atoi vs atol vs strtol vs strtoul vs sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22865622/6872717)

None of those pleased me.  `strtol()` (and its family) is the safest standard one and also a very fast one, but it is incredibly difficult to use, so I decided to write a safe and simple interface to it.  `strtoi()` (libbsd) is easier to use than `strtol()`, but still a bit complicated.  I decided to use fixed-width integers, as I do in all my code.  I also did an interface for `strtof()` and company.

Requisites:

- **libbsd** (The following code can be written in terms of `strtol()` instead of `strtoi()` if libbsd is not available, but it is more complex, and has a problem with `errno` which `strtoi()` hasn't).
- GNU C11 (not actually needed, but I use it for added safety/optimizations).

---

Signed integers:

`strtoi_s.h`:

```
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/strto/strtoi_s.h */


#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>


__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     strtoi8_s   (int8_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base);
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     strtoi16_s  (int16_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base);
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     strtoi32_s  (int32_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base);
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     strtoi64_s  (int64_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base);


inline
int     strtoi8_s   (int8_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base)
{
        int     rstatus;

        *num    = strtoi(str, NULL, base, INT8_MIN, INT8_MAX, &rstatus);

        switch (rstatus) {
        case 0:
                return  0;
        case ENOTSUP:
                return  rstatus;
        case ECANCELED:
        case EINVAL:
        case ERANGE:
        default:
                return  -rstatus;
        }
}

inline
int     strtoi16_s  (int16_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base)
{
        int     rstatus;

        *num    = strtoi(str, NULL, base, INT16_MIN, INT16_MAX, &rstatus);

        switch (rstatus) {
        case 0:
                return  0;
        case ENOTSUP:
                return  rstatus;
        case ECANCELED:
        case EINVAL:
        case ERANGE:
        default:
                return  -rstatus;
        }
}

inline
int     strtoi32_s  (int32_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base)
{
        int     rstatus;

        *num    = strtoi(str, NULL, base, INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX, &rstatus);

        switch (rstatus) {
        case 0:
                return  0;
        case ENOTSUP:
                return  rstatus;
        case ECANCELED:
        case EINVAL:
        case ERANGE:
        default:
                return  -rstatus;
        }
}

inline
int     strtoi64_s  (int64_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base)
{
        int     rstatus;

        *num    = strtoi(str, NULL, base, INT64_MIN, INT64_MAX, &rstatus);

        switch (rstatus) {
        case 0:
                return  0;
        case ENOTSUP:
                return  rstatus;
        case ECANCELED:
        case EINVAL:
        case ERANGE:
        default:
                return  -rstatus;
        }
}
```

Unsigned integers:

It's mostly the same as the previous one, so I'll post only a function

`strtou_s.h`:

```
inline
int     strtou8_s   (uint8_t *restrict num, const char *restrict str,
                     int base)
{
        int     rstatus;

        *num    = strtou(str, NULL, base, 0, UINT8_MAX, &rstatus);

        switch (rstatus) {
        case 0:
                return  0;
        case ENOTSUP:
                return  rstatus;
        case ECANCELED:
        case EINVAL:
        case ERANGE:
        default:
                return  -rstatus;
        }
}
```

Floating-point:

`strtof_s.h`:

```
#pragma once    /* libalx/base/stdlib/strto/strtof_s.h */


#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
 * `errno` needs to be cleared before calling these functions.  If not, false
 * negatives could happen (the function succeds, but it reports error).
 */
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     strtod_s    (double *restrict num, const char *restrict str);
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     strtof_s    (float *restrict num, const char *restrict str);
__attribute__((nonnull, warn_unused_result))
inline
int     strtold_s   (long double *restrict num, const char *restrict str);


inline
int     strtod_s    (double *restrict num, const char *restrict str)
{
        char    *endptr;

        *num    = strtod(str, &endptr);

        if (*endptr != '\0')
                return  ENOTSUP;
        if (errno == ERANGE)
                return  ERANGE;
        if (str == endptr)
                return  -ECANCELED;

        return  0;
}

inline
int     strtof_s    (float *restrict num, const char *restrict str)
{
        char    *endptr;

        *num    = strtof(str, &endptr);

        if (*endptr != '\0')
                return  ENOTSUP;
        if (errno == ERANGE)
                return  ERANGE;
        if (str == endptr)
                return  -ECANCELED;

        return  0;
}

inline
int     strtold_s   (long double *restrict num, const char *restrict str)
{
        char    *endptr;

        *num    = strtold(str, &endptr);

        if (*endptr != '\0')
                return  ENOTSUP;
        if (errno == ERANGE)
                return  ERANGE;
        if (str == endptr)
                return  -ECANCELED;

        return  0;
}
```

---

The functions take two pointers:  the first one to the variable where the number has to be stored; and the second one to the string to be read.  The integer functions also require the base, which follows the same rules as in `strtol()`.

The return value is simply an error code:

`0` is OK as always,

`> 0` means a valid conversion with some error (partial conversion, 0 or inf in floating-point, ...).

`< 0` means an invalid conversion, or no conversion at all.

Example:

```
char    buf[BUFSIZ];
int64_t num;

if (!fgets(buf, ARRAY_SIZE(buf), stdin))
        goto err;
if (strtoi64_s(&num, buf, 0))
        goto err;

/* num is safe to be used now*/
```

Do you think the interface can be improved in any way?

Comment: "(strtol) is more complex, and has a problem with errno" and "I also did an interface for strtof() and company." is curious.  `strtof()` and family is harder/more complex to use than `strtol()`.  If code can well handle `strofd()` with all its issues, `strtol()` is relatively easy.

Comment: @chux By more complex I meant that you have to handle more than one variable, as with `strtof()`, not extremely more complex. And it has the added problem that I already have with `strtof_s()`: if `errno` isn't reset, the return value is wrong, but it's also a minor problem.  Not something very problematic, of course, but I prefer to avoid it even if it means using less portable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Portability**

To be clear, `strtoi()` and `strtou()` that OP's code relies on is not in the standard C library.  OP's code is limited to the requisites.

`strtol()` may be more complex, yet it is portable throughout all compliant C implementations.

**Bug - failure to clear `errno`**

When `strtod()` succeeds, it does not change `errno`, so the tests on `errno` are testing the prior state.  Add `errno = 0;` before calling `strtod()`, `strtof()`, `strtold()`.

```
    errno = 0; // add
    *num    = strtod(str, &endptr);
    if (*endptr != '\0') return  ENOTSUP;
    if (errno == ERANGE) return  ERANGE;
    ...
```

**Questionable error**

With floating point conversions, input like `"z"`, the functions indicate `ENOTSUP`.  I'd expect `ECANCELED`

Rather than

```
    if (*endptr != '\0') return  ENOTSUP;
    if (errno == ERANGE) return  ERANGE;
    if (str == endptr)   return  -ECANCELED;
```

Consider

```
    if (str == endptr)   return  -ECANCELED;
    if (*endptr != '\0') return  ENOTSUP;
    if (errno == ERANGE) return  ERANGE;
```

**Questionable cases**

With `"1.0e100000"`?  A floating point value with infinity with an `ERANGE` error?

With `"INF"`?  A floating point value with infinity with an no error?

**Careful about `ERANGE` on the small side**

When the string indicates a small value like `1e-100000`, this may or may not set `errno = ERANGE`.

C allows that.  C also allows `errno` to not be set on *underflow*.

[Linux man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) has "If the correct value would cause underflow, zero is returned and ERANGE is stored in errno."

It is unclear to me what `libbsd` or OP wants in this case.

---

There are additional issues anytime the string would convert to a value smaller in magnitude than `DBL_MIN`.  This lack of crispness in `strtod()` specification renders *string* in the converted range of `DBL_MIN` and `DBL_TRUE_MIN` troublesome.

**String to number design**

Most string to number functions tolerate leading spaces.  I find it curious that most such functions do not well tolerate trailing white-space.

IMO, such functions should  - very convenient for reading and converting a *line* of input like `"123\n"`.  Perhaps as:

```
number = strto*(string, &endptr);

if (string == endptr) return fail_no_conversion;
while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) {
  endptr++;
}
// Now test for null character
if (*endptr) return fail_junk_at_the_end;
...
```

Comment: *Bug - failure to clear `errno`*: I prefer to not clear `errno` in any of my library functions, just as standard library functions do.  For that reason I wrote the note acknowledging the bug.  Nevertheless, it's unlikely to find `errno` already with the value `ERANGE` without knowing just before calling this function.

Comment: *Questionable error*: Very good point!

Comment: *Questionable cases*: My point there is that is you wrote `"INF"` the variable stores exactly what you meant, but if you wrote `"1.0e100000"` it has lost some important information, so a positive return value indicates that.

Comment: *Trailing white-space:* very good point!

Comment: @CacahueteFrito  Re: [unlikely to find errno already with the value `ERANGE`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226969/safe-and-simple-strtol/227362#comment442543_227362) If one calls `strtod_s(too_big)` and it sets `errno=ERANGE`, then next calls to `strtod_s(in_range)` will still have `ERANGE` set.  Sounds like you are obliging the caller to clear `errno` with the FP functions, yet not the integer ones - asymmetric functionality.  Your call.

Comment: Re:Re: `ERANGE`: Ok, a solution would be to store the value of `errno` in a local variable, and restore it later if it hasn't been set during the call. Would you agree?

Comment: *Careful about `ERANGE` on small side*:  POSIX makes it mandatory to set `errno` on underflow: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtof.html

Comment: BTW, I did that of the trailing space, and for that it was easier to use good old `strtol()`, so as a side effect it is more portable now :)  Also, now all of the functions share the same error handling function.

Comment: Also note that fuzzers like to fail in strtol() with non zro-terminated strings. Before calling strtol or sscanf ensure that your string is really a string, i.e. it is zero-terminated. All string functions are unsafe if so.

Answer (score 3):

- The main advantage of `strtol` and family is that they compute (for free!) the point where the conversion ended. It is a very valuable information, because usually after extracting the number you want to continue parsing. Your wrappers throw it away.
- DRY. The switches (which compute `result`) for integral types is identical. Factor it out into a function.

Comment: Good points.  For the first point, I could add a parameter `ptrdiff_t *read` at the end and use `nonnull(1, 2)`, so that the user can read it or ignore it passing `NULL` (a `char **` would be another possibility, but I prefer the length, and they're easily interchangeable).

Comment: For the second one, I will use a helper `int strtoi_status(int rstatus);`.  BTW, for the floating point status computation I will also write a helper: `int strtof_status(const char *restrict str,
     const char *restrict endptr, int _errno);`